# Animar texto com Python

Tags: python, texto

Eu gostaria de saber se existe algum meio de gerar textos animados na tela com Python.
Eu queria fazer um texto aparecer na tela e depois sumir, como uma tela de carregamento em que três pontos aparecem e depois somem.

Eu consegui fazer as letras aparecerem uma após a outra usando essa lógica:

```
import sys
frase = 'frase animada'
while True:
    for letra in list(frase):
        print(letra)
        sys.stdouy.flush()
```

Existe alguma maneira de fazer o texto sumir e depois reaparecer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você pode utilizar o parametro end do print passando "\r" onde ele ira reescrever
o valor da mesma linha com o novo valor

```py
import time

logs = [
        "Loading."
        "Loading.."
        "Loading..."
        "Loading...."
        "Loading....."
]

for l in logs:
  time.sleep(1)
  print(l, end="\r")
```

para que você consiga ver ele apagando e reescrevendo a linha é necessário adicionar um sleep

complementando, caso seu desenho  não caiba em 1 unico print você consegue utilizar o comando os.system()
onde executa um comando  do terminal então seria possível limpar o terminal para cada "frame" da sua animação.

```py
import os

print("----")
print("|  |")
print("|  |")
print("----")

#output
#----
#|  |
#----

#limpa o terminal
os.system("cls")
print("outro frame")

#ouput
#outro frame
```